# Multiplication in for loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I am new to JS and I am completely stuck with this simple thing and I would really like to understand this and continue further with learning.

I have this chunk of code:

```
var power = function(base, exponent) {
  var result = 1;
  for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++) {
    result *= base;
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(power(2, 10));
// Result is: 1024
```

A result in the console will be 1024

If I change values into:

```
console.log(power(1, 10));
// Result is: 1
```

But if I change into:

```
console.log(power(3, 10));
// Result is: 59049
```

I will get a result of 59049.

So, how I got this result of 59049? How I got a result of 1024? How I got a result of 1? How does all this thing work?

I would really appreciate if someone can explain it to me on as simplest and dummies way as possible :)

Thanks!

Comment: I would start by reading [`function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), then learn how to [debug JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript).

Comment: Is there a specific piece of this you don't understand or is it completely foreign like you don't understand what a `var` is

Comment: I'd recommend you run this through a debugger, since that's what'll show you what happens when.

Comment: Are you asking how exponents work? The function just takes a base and returns the base multiplied by itself `n`(exponent) times. `1^3` is `1x1x1` is `1` and `3^3` is `3x3x3` is `9`.

Comment: @imjared No, no... I understand what `var` is... what confusing me is the line of code `result *= base;` and how the results are dramatically changing, for example, if I set values to `1, 10` a result is **1**, but if I set `2, 10` a result goes high on **1024*, and if I set values to `3, 10` a result goes way higher on **59049**. How, what's going on there? How it's multiplying under the hood?

Comment: @mickbrancco - thanks for the clarification, so what you seem to be unfamiliar with is that `result *= base` is shorthand for `result = result * base`. There are similar abbreviations for other operators like `+` and `-` as well (and not just in JS, but in other languages too). So it's well worth getting familiar with them - `+=` in particular is used quite a lot.

Comment: @RobinZigmond thanks for the comment, basically I know for basic operators and shorthands, but what I didn't know is about **exponential**

Comment: @George thanks for clarification! I will definitely read more about **exponential** since you clarified a lot!

Comment: well exponentiatiation is more of a mathematical concept than a programming one. JS doesn't actually have an operator for it (although you can do it with the function `Math.pow`). What the piece of code we're discussing does is actually perform the exponentiation operations - but using only more "basic" operations. A good example of how in programming you can achieve complex things using simple building blocks :)

Comment: @RobinZigmond "JS doesn't actually have an operator for it" Yes it does! `**` was introduced in 2015.

Comment: @jhpratt - thanks, I didn't actually know that! I'm familiar with much of ES2015 but there's always little bits and pieces you can miss. Although according to MDN it was actually introduced in ES2016: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Specifications Thanks all the same :)

Comment: @RobinZigmond if this is a basic of JS and I already stuck, then I will never succeed in JS and will never become javascript or react developer which makes me really sad :( But thanks for clarification anyway! :)

Comment: @mickbrancco don't give up, we all have to start somewhere! (I learnt from scratch to be a developer only last year :) ) It seems like your only problem was not realising what `*=` means - don't worry, unfamiliar syntax is something you'll always come across, just remember Google is your friend :)

Comment: @mickbrancco A book is probably the best way to get to grips with js. Though there's also a bunch of interactive tutorial thingy's that are apparently good, couldn't tell you which one to go for but codecademy is one of them, there's also some good tutorial resources on the mdn. As a side note, you'll probably never see exponentials pop up in web-dev. Most of the math involved is fairly straight forward, and learnable as you go, especially once you're able to read js (which won't take long). You don't need to give up! :)

Comment: Thanks @RobinZigmond I am definitely determined to continue :)

Comment: @George yeah this is definitely something that I need to take a look first, a BOOK with basics before I start doing some ad hoc things without having a basics and then fighting to figure out something :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because

> 2 to the power of 10 (or 1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2) equals 1024

and

> 1 to the power of 10 (or 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1) equals 1

and

> 3 to the power of 10 (or 1 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3) equals 59049

If you supply your function with a base and an exponent, the function will do the following:

power(2, 0) yields 1 because exponent is 0 and the function immidiately returns result (which is 1) without entering the loop.

power(2, 1) yields 2 because result (which is 1) is multiplied once with base (which is 2) in your loop thus resulting in 1 * 2 = 2

power(2, 2) yields 4 because result (which is 1) is multiplied twice with base (which is 2) in your loop thus resulting in 1 * 2 * 2 = 4

power(2, 3) yields 8 because result (which is 1) is multiplied three times with base (which is 2) in your loop thus resulting in 1 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 8

Comment: Oh, God! I never thought it works that way! So then if I change values to `3, 9` a result will be **19683** because in that case 3 is multiplying 9 times... Huh! Ok, thanks for the answer! It helped me clarify this basic thing!